# Report generation in server

Tags: asp.net, web-services, com, ms-word, thread-safety

i'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document` to generate the report document in server and download it for user.

Is it really good approach to do like this using Interop to perform word operations?. Is it thread safe?. are there any alternatives way you can suggest to perform word operation in server?. I googled lot, found Interop is not safe, you should have word installed in server to generate document etc all issues... But can you please tell me its correct approach or not?

Comment: Word server side (it needs word installed on the server) is officially not supported, but it doesn't mean it doesn't work. It means you *will* run into problems. Most problem you can overcome using try catch, retries, kill the process and restart it, etc. You probably also need to serialize access to word (with mutexes, etc.)

Comment: Word will throw message boxes and prompts at you at times you wouldn't dream of. On the server, there is nobody to click Ok. you can't click Ok via automation either. It just freezes. And that's just when thing behave as-designed. It's Ok for an ad-hoc situation if you program-in a good restart strategy, and you don't mind literally **babysitting** your web server ready to restart it *when* it stops working. Anything else is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an official KB article explaining why it's a bad idea, and listing alternatives:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

> Is it really good approach to do like this using Interop to perform word operations?

No, it's not - for the reasons listed in that article.

> Is it thread safe?

Kind of. Because there are no threads in word API. Word API runs as STA (single-threaded-apartment), so all your API calls will run in one single thread of the word application.

> are there any alternatives way you can suggest to perform word operation in server?

First, check out the above article - it has a list of alternatives. There are also libraries which can generate word documents (especially in .docx xml format, there are not that many in the old .doc format).

> you should have word installed in server to generate document

Not only you should have it installed on server, but also the user who uses your website (which, in turn, uses Word). Read the article above - it's a licensing requirement.

> But can you please tell me its correct approach or not?

It's a bad idea for production.